# Mellin transform of $\sin(\pi x)\left(\frac{d}{dx}\log\left(x;j^{-1}\right)\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, mellin-transform, q-series

Consider the smooth function :
$$f(x)=\sin(\pi x)\left(\frac{d}{dx}\log\left(x;j^{-1}\right)\right)$$
$\left(z;q\right)$ being the [Q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), and $j$ is a positive integer.

We want to compute the Mellin transform of $f(x)$, that is :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)x^{s-1}dx$$
Any good idea on how to do this integral ?

Comment: You have the derivative of the log thing in the integral, so integration by parts should be doable.

Comment: It's doable, but we still have to integrate terms of the form $\sin(\pi x)\log\left(1-\frac{x}{j^{k}}\right)x^{s}$ and $\cos(\pi x)\log\left(1-\frac{x}{j^{k}}\right)x^{s-1}$ .

Comment: Looks tricky. You may find Ramanujan's Master Theorem helpful, but no guarantees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem

Comment: The discrete Q-Pochammer symbol has the form $(x;q)_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-xq^k),$ the logarithmic derivative of which is
$-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{q^k}{1-xq^k}.$

Comment: $(x;j^{-1})$ should be understood as $(x;j^{-1})_{\infty}=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{j^{k}}\right)$, and thus $\frac{d}{dx}\log(x;j^{-1})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-j^{k}}$